# Cut out or remove the pixels from an image that run into the black pixels of a mask

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to cut out two images with OpenCV using Python.

The idea is to use an image like this one:

[image]

As a mask. Note: this is only an example.

So if I subtract this mask to another image, I will get an image with the original pixels only in the same location as the white rectangle in the mask. So, the idea is to remove the pixels from the first image that run into the same location that the black ones in the mask.

How can I do it?

Maybe I can do an **AND** operation between the two images (the mask will have only 0 (for black) and 1 (for white pixels).

Comment: Why not just invert the mask and bitwise_and with that? `inverted_mask = 255 - mask`

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Do you want them transparent or possibly white? Or do you want to crop the image to the same bounds as the white rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it.

Input arrays have a shape of `(240, 240)` and output array has a shape of `(240, 240)`.

I will mask the indices on `image` array with the indices in `mask` array which have a value of 0.

```
def cut_out(image, mask):
    if type(image) != np.ndarray:
        raise TypeError("image must be a Numpy array")
    elif type(mask) != np.ndarray:
        raise TypeError("mask must be a Numpy array")
    elif image.shape != mask.shape:
        raise ValueError("image and mask must have the same shape")

    return np.where(mask==0, 0, image)
```

Answer (score 5):

If what you are asking is how to make the image transparent where the mask is black and opaque where the mask is white, then just add the mask to the alpha channel of the input. Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV. (Revised per comment by Mark Setchell)

Input:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')

# load mask as grayscale
mask = cv2.imread('rect_mask.png', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# put mask into alpha channel of image
#result = img.copy()
#result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
#result[:, :, 3] = mask
result = np.dstack((img, mask))

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('lena_masked.png', result)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Or more simply, replace the 3 lines beginning with `result` with `result = np.dstack((img,mask))`

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, Mark. Edited accordingly

Comment: My image is the same size. Please download it and you will see that. The rest of the image is transparent, so when viewing here the background is white and so does not show up. So it looks smaller.

Comment: I haven't written down the image to a file. In my case `img` and `mask` are Numpy arrays with a shape of `(240, 240)`, and result is `(240, 240, 2)`. Is that correct, because I need result with a `(240, 240)` shape.

Comment: My input is (256,256,3) for color. My resulting image includes the alpha channel, so (256,256,4), i.e. 4 channels. If your input is (240,240) that means it is grayscale. So if you add the mask via np.dstack(), you would have (240,240,2).

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks. I have found another to do it. Thanks a lot for your time and support. Sorry, I can upvote you more.